# Using Python builtin library in subproject of a Python project in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-builtins

I've started with a python project in PyCharm (2023.2.1 Community Edition) with only one module/project to which I have added another project that sits at the same level as the first project in the project exlorer. It is meant to work independently of the first one.

The problem I'm facing: I cannot use Python builtin-functions in Project 2, specifically `open()`, I get an error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'` with `module1` being a source folder in the first project.

What I've tried:

- Mark a folder in the new project as source folder and add an `__init__.py` file. I understood this is the way builtin functions can be called.
- Promote the new project repository standalone project status by going *File > Close Project* and reopen. Under settings, I now see *Project: Name_Of_New_Project*.
- Edit *File > Settings  Project Structure*. Make sure the source folders a listet.

Running the code, I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'`. I cannot even locate where `module1` is specified so I can edit it. Anyone knows what to do?